# ASP.NET Core Identity 2FA with Authenticator app in ASP.NEt Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity, multi-factor-authentication, authenticator

I am developing an API in ASP.NET Core 8 using ASP.NET Core identity which uses 2FA  with Authenticator app for users who have enabled it.

The problem is this. I have checked on the 2FA  with Authenticator app implementation in Razor pages, and it creates a cookie by the name `Identity.TwoFactorUserId` and has value `CfDJ8MEoYd_uBmxNsdLp...` when the user logins with user name and password who has enabled 2FA. And this cookie is used to identify the user and validate the 2FA code from the Authenticator app

[image]

In my case I am using JWT for my API. So once a user who has enabled 2FA  with Authenticator app logins with username and password, he will be prompted to enter the code from the  authenticator app. But with my API, there is no way to identify the user when validating the 2FA code. How can i generate a code like above in the cookie which is like `Identity.TwoFactorUserId` and has value `CfDJ8MEoYd_uBmxNsdLp...` in my API? or is there any other better way so that once the user enters the username and passowrd, then i can send him the  `Identity.TwoFactorUserId` like code so that the front end will again pass the same code with the 2FA code to identify the user?

Comment: _"In my case i am using JWT for my AP"_ - Websites used by web-browsers can't use JWTs - they need to use normal browser cookies. If you have a web-service API that's used by non-human-driven clients then that's fine, but from a security perspective it's entirely separate from your web-application.

Comment: ...and I say "**can't**" with emphaiss, because using browser-based `fetch()` to authenticate using OAuth2/OIDC `implicit` flow (such that the JS code holds the `access_token` in-memory) [is woefully insecure and prohibited in the next and upcoming revisions of OAuth and OIDC.](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-1-10#name-removal-of-the-oauth-20-imp).

Comment: _"But with my API, there is no way to identify the user when validating the 2FA code."_ - You misunderstand the purpose of bearer-tokens: they're only issued **after** you authenticate the subject, and 2FA is part of authentication: it should not be possible to obtain a JWT bearer token for your system without having first authenticated through a browser-based flow (the only exception is non-human clients using `client_credentials` flow, but those _won't_ be issued any tokens containing claims for a human user) so there's no problem there.

Comment: yes, im issuing the jwt after the 2fa verification. no issue with that.

Comment: So what's the problem then? You don't necessarily need to issue a cookie in-between the username+password step and the 2FA step: an `<input type="hidden">` does the same job (and arguably more reliably too).

Comment: @Dai when you say "can't" you really mean "shouldn't"

Comment: @possum If you're using an RFC-compliant IdP then you _literally won't be able to_ because an RFC-compliant IdP won't issue a token to an insecure client. But I will concede that if you intentionally reconfigure a self-hosted IdP to allow `implicit` grants then yes, you technically _can_ - but it's just a really bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

For temporary token you could generate random string with the expiration time. by using this token you can maintain the state between login and 2FA verification.

sample code:

2FA Initiation:

```
public IActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
{
    // ... Login code

    if (IsTwoFactorRequired(user))
    {
        var twoFactorToken = GenerateTwoFactorToken(user.Id);
        // Save the token somewhere e.g database, with expiration time
        StoreTwoFactorToken(twoFactorToken);

        // Return this token to the client
        return Ok(new { twoFactorToken });
    }

    // ... Generate JWT if not using 2FA
}
```

Generate a token for the user, could be a GUID, or an encrypted value that contains the user ID:

```
private string GenerateTwoFactorToken(string userId)
{
    return Convert.ToBase64String(RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(64));
}
```

2FA Verification:

```
public IActionResult VerifyTwoFactor(string twoFactorToken, string twoFactorCode)
{
    if (ValidateTwoFactorToken(twoFactorToken))
    {
        // Get the user based on the Token
        var userId = GetUserIdFromToken(twoFactorToken);

        if (ValidateTwoFactorCode(userId, twoFactorCode))
        {
            // Generate JWT and return to the client
            var token = GenerateJwtToken(userId);
            return Ok(new { token });
        }
    }

    return Unauthorized();
}
```

Validate the format and, optionally, the existence of the token in the database or cache:

```
private bool ValidateTwoFactorToken(string twoFactorToken)
{
    // Token validation code
}
```

Comment: _"You can't use cookie as apis are meant to be stateless."_ - Cookies have nothing to do with whether or not a web-service is stateless or not: a cookie is just a browser-managed state-blob, just like a bearer-token is for non-browser-based clients. I imagine you're thinking of server-side _session-state_ (which is predicated on having some kind of lightweight, reference-based, _session-cookie_) - but that's not the same thing as saying using any cookies make a web-service stateful (because they don't).